# Get XML Line with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I am searching for a Function where the parameter is a Integer(Line) and the return value gives the xml-Line to that Integer.

I have a large XMl File and i want to decrease it into a number of smaller ones. Every Output File has a Start Tag and End Tag

e.g.

Input File.:
Test.xml

Output Files :

Test1.xml
Test2.xml
Test3.xml
Test4.xml

```
tree = etree.parse(file_name)
root = tree.getroot()

# Here i count the number of XMl Lines in my file
xml_lines = 0

for child in root:
    xml_lines +=1

# Here i want to get the String of my XMl Line by giving the number
for i in range(counter,counter+number_of_each_file):
            d.write(FUNCTION)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your approach about splitting the big XML file into smaller XML files. XML does not care about lines. It cares about element. Your function should get the root of the big XML,dest_file_name_prefix and a number that represent the desired elements in a each small XML file.

Something like:

```
def split_xml(root,dest_file_name_prefix,num_of_elements):
    """ Loop around the elements under to root and save a each collection of 'num_of_elements' to a file  having a unique  name """
    root = tree.getroot()
    elements = root.findall('.//element')
    counter = 0 
    temp = []
    for idx,element in enumerate(elements)
        temp.append(element)
        if idx > 0 and idx % num_of_elements == 0:
            # save the elements to a 'small' file
            counter += 1
            file_name = '{}_{}'.format(dest_file_name_prefix,counter)
            #TODO I assume you know how to save the elements from temp to a file  
            temp = []
```

Big XML example

```
<root>
   <element id="0"></element>
   <element id="1"></element>
   <element id="2"></element>
   ...
   <element id="10000"></element>
</root>
```